# What does the Reddening line represents in this U-B vs B-V plot?

Tags: star, nebula, black-body, color-index

The plot is from this [paper](http://articles.adsabs.harvard.edu/cgi-bin/nph-iarticle_query?1961ApJ...133..874A&defaultprint=YES&filetype=.pdf) (pg-8). [image: Colo-Color diagram for Blackbody and stars]

They have also talked(in the same [paper](http://articles.adsabs.harvard.edu/cgi-bin/nph-iarticle_query?1961ApJ...133..874A&defaultprint=YES&filetype=.pdf)) about how central stars from galactic longitude range $20^\circ-80^\circ$ will have a very unusual *Reddening* line (pg-9). The current plot is for central stars from the galactic longitude range $200^\circ-300^\circ$

> The group
> of planetary nuclei plotted here are all those occurring in galactic longitudes 200o
> -300°.
> In the longitude range from 20° to 80° the points fall to the right of the reddening line in
> Figure 3 (not plotted). If the latter energy-curves are well-behaved, a very unusual
> reddening line would be needed to explain their position in the diagram. This is a puzzling result which is unexplained at present.

My interpretation of *Reddening* line: It is showing that if we plot real star data where the sample contains all the stars from bluer end to redder end on this **U-B vs B-V** plot, we will get  the *Reddening*
line on the plot.

Is this interpretation correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reddening line is the locus that a star would move along in a colour-colour diagram as the interstellar reddening towards it increases.

i.e. It is an equation on the colour-colour plot of the form (for this colour-colour plot)
$$E(U-B) = f(E(B-V)) + c\ ,$$
where $E(U-B)$ is the colour excess in $U-B$ due to interstellar reddening, $E(B-V)$ is the colour excess in $B-V$ and $c$ is a constant chosen so that the locus would go through a star of the same spectral type but with no interstellar reddening.

Typically, for low reddening and a typical interstellar medium
$$ E(U-B) = 0.72 E(B-V) + 0.05 (E(B-V))^2\ ,$$
which I imagine is the line drawn on the plot you show.

To establish the reddening to a particular star you can follow it back from its observed position in the colour-colour plot, along a reddening line, until it intersects the main sequence locus (if it *is* a main sequence star). The intersection would give its unreddened, intrinsic colours and the x-axis increment through which you traced it back would give its $E(B-V)$.

Comment: Thank you sir for the amazing and apt answer.